# Android Login and Register

Tags: java, android, authentication

I have created and app that allows the user to register a username and password, save it to a database and then login to a system. I thought the code was correct and there is no errors, but i don't think my buttons are working to actually carry out the tasks. Below is my code:

Main Activity

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity implements View.OnClickListener {

TextView tvRegisterLink;


DatabaseHelper helper = new DatabaseHelper(this);
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    tvRegisterLink = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.tvRegisterLink);

    tvRegisterLink.setOnClickListener(this);
}

public void onButtonClick(View v)
{
    if(v.getId() == R.id.bLogin)
    {
        EditText a = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.etUsername);
        String str = a.getText().toString();
        EditText b = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.etPassword);
        String pass = b.getText().toString();

        String password = helper.searchPass(str);
        if(pass.equals(password))
        {
            Intent i = new Intent(MainActivity.this, Options.class);
            i.putExtra("Username",str);
            startActivity(i);
        }
        else
        {
            Toast temp = Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this , "Username and Password Dont Match!" , Toast.LENGTH_SHORT);
            temp.show();
        }
    }
}

@Override
public void onClick(View v) {
    switch(v.getId()){
        case R.id.tvRegisterLink:
            startActivity(new Intent(this, register.class));

            break;
    }
}

}
```

Register Class:

```
public class register extends AppCompatActivity {

DatabaseHelper helper = new DatabaseHelper(this);
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_register);
}

public void onbRegisterClick(View v)
{
    if(v.getId() == R.id.bRegister)
    {
        EditText username = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.RegUsername);
        EditText password = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.RegPassword);
        EditText password2 = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.RegPassword2);

        String usernamestr = username.getText().toString();
        String passwordstr = password.getText().toString();
        String password2str = password2.getText().toString();

        if(!passwordstr.equals(password2str))
        {
            //pop-up message
            Toast pass = Toast.makeText(register.this , "Passwords Do Not Match!" , Toast.LENGTH_SHORT);
            pass.show();
        }
        else
        {
            //insert the details in the database
            Contact c = new Contact();
            c.setUsername(usernamestr);
            c.setPassword(passwordstr);

            helper.insertContact(c);
        }
    }
}
}
```

Im fairly certain it has something to do with the onButtonClick method in the main activity and the onbRegisterClick method in the register because they are both saying that the methods are not being used.
Any help at all is greatly appreciated!

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:padding="10dp"
android:orientation="vertical">

<TextView
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:text="Username"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content" />

<EditText
    android:id="@+id/etUsername"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content" />

<TextView
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:text="Password"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content" />

<EditText
    android:id="@+id/etPassword"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:inputType="textPassword"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content" />

<Button
    android:id="@+id/bLogin"
    android:text="Login"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content" />

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/tvRegisterLink"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:text="Register Here"
    android:textStyle="bold"
    android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content" />

</LinearLayout>
```

Comment: I man my bad .saw it just now . So you have written implementations but your are not calling these functions anywhere .what exactly is the requirement here .let me know ill let you know what to fix .

Comment: Basically, ive created a local db and the button in the register class is meant to save the username and password entered into the database and then the button in the main activity verifies the username and password in the database and lets the user log into the system, but the buttons dont seem to work and im sure ive got all of the database code right

Comment: Please edit your question to include the layout XMLs for both activities. Do you have a `android:onClick` on your buttons?

Comment: So main activity creates the user in db onclick of register button and then where do you want to verify ?

Comment: I think the main activity does verify it already, the button does it?

Answer (score 0):

In your xml make textview property clickable as true and it should work just fine .

Comment: The textview click works just fine, its the actual buttons that don't. I dont think the methods have been called properly for the buttons to work and therefore has resulted in dead code. But i do not know how to call them properly as I thought I already had

Answer (score -1):

Put your

```
EditText a = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.etUsername);
EditText b = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.etPassword);
```

and

```
EditText username = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.RegUsername);
EditText password = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.RegPassword);
EditText password2 = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.RegPassword2);
```

in your onCreate method.

You could do like this:

```
EditText a, b;

**EIDT**
Button btnLogin;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

a = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.etUsername);
b = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.etPassword);

**EIDT**
btnLogin = (Button) findViewById(R.id.bLogin);


btnLogin.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {


    String str = a.getText().toString();

    String pass = b.getText().toString();

    String password = helper.searchPass(str);
    if(pass.equals(password))
    {
        Intent i = new Intent(MainActivity.this, Options.class);
        i.putExtra("Username",str);
        startActivity(i);
    }
    else
    {
        Toast temp = Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this , "Username and Password Dont Match!" , Toast.LENGTH_SHORT);
        temp.show();
    }

  }
}
```

Comment: I think op is confused as of now . His button clicks are unrecognisable .once he tells us requirement we fix it

Comment: All those are fine within a click listener

Comment: I dont have a click listener, I dont know where to put it?

Comment: This is your method public void onButtonClick(View v). How come that you dont have it?

Comment: I dont know? The onButtonClick says that the method is never used, so I would imagine thats the problem?

Comment: Place your xml. I dont see that you have declared your buttons.

Comment: what xml do you mean?

Comment: R.layout.activity_main

Comment: So Ben first you have to move your findviewbyid and onlcicklister into Oncreate method just as you are doing for all other strings .now within the default onclick method which you have overridden In main activity write one more case of when r.id.button is equal to view.getid then perform login. You have to findviewbyid of button and setonlcikster on it in Oncreate as well .i have the full code but can't post from phone .grrggh

Comment: If you get onto a computer, post it in edits for me so I see what you mean properly please, thanks

Comment: I have post edits in my answer, you just need to remove `implements View.OnClickListener` from your `MainActivity` .

Comment: That hasnt worked, its still bringing up errors and the app is crashing

Comment: Place your log file here.

Comment: What you mean my log file?

Comment: Sorry, i have switched brackets, maybe this cause error. See now how brackets are set.